# Horizontally center two DIVs and have the distance between them scale with the browser width

Tags: html, css

I am making a Star Wars fansite and I have this setup. I need to make "legends-title" and "canon-title" horizontally centered in the larger div and have the space between them resize with the browser. (essentially, it should act as if I had created a 2-column table and horizontally centered the columns and when the browser resizes, the gap between them should resize to stay directly in the center of the left/right half of the div).

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/L1sz0atL/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="starwars-header">
 <div id="legends-title">LEGENDS</div>
 <div id="canon-title">CANON</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#starwars-header {
 background: rgb(54, 75, 95); /* Fall-back for browsers that don't support rgba */
 background: rgba(54,75, 95, .9);
 border: 5px solid black; /*width-style-color*/
 text-align: center;
}

#legends-title{
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 background-color: green;
}

#canon-title {
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're after. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wnLgebx2/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flexbox` - [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1sz0atL/4/)

```css
#starwars-header {
  background: rgb(54, 75, 95); /* Fall-back for browsers that don't support rgba */
  background: rgba(54,75, 95, .9);
  border: 5px solid black; /*width-style-color*/
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  }
#legends-title{
     display: inline-block;
     color: white;
     background-color: green;
}
#canon-title {
     display: inline-block;
     color: white;
     background-color: red;
     /*padding-left: 10%; This increases*/
}
```

```html
<div id="starwars-header">
    <div id="legends-title">LEGENDS</div>
    <div id="canon-title">CANON</div>
</div>
```

---

A second option, `flexbox` combined with pseudo elements on `#starwars-header` - [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1sz0atL/6/)

```css
#starwars-header {
  background: rgb(54, 75, 95); /* Fall-back for browsers that don't support rgba */
  background: rgba(54,75, 95, .9);
  border: 5px solid black; /*width-style-color*/
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
#starwars-header::before,
#starwars-header::after {
  content: '';
}
#legends-title{
     display: inline-block;
     color: white;
     background-color: green;
}
#canon-title {
     display: inline-block;
     color: white;
     background-color: red;
     /*padding-left: 10%; This increases*/
}
```

```html
<div id="starwars-header">
    <div id="legends-title">LEGENDS</div>
    <div id="canon-title">CANON</div>
</div>
```

Comment: My world has just become more "flex"ible!

Answer (score 0):

```css
#starwars-header {
 background: rgb(54, 75, 95); /* Fall-back for browsers that don't support rgba */
 background: rgba(54,75, 95, .9);
 border: 5px solid black; /*width-style-color*/
 text-align: center;
}
#legends-title{
     display: inline-block;
     color: white;
     background-color: green;
     text-align: center;
     width: calc(50% - 1px);// calculate your width 50% minus the border pixels
}
#canon-title {
     display: inline-block;
     color: white;
     background-color: red;
     text-align: center;
     float: right;
     width: calc(50% - 1px); // calculate your width 50% minus the border pixels
}
```

```html
<div id="starwars-header">
 <div id="legends-title">LEGENDS</div>
 <div id="canon-title">CANON</div>
</div>
```

Is that what was needed?

You can move the center align style into the divs themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The answers of **Kate** and **LGSon** solve your problem.

I'm here to send you another possible solution too. What you need is a **CSS Grid System**.

I forked your fiddle with an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/rcheruti/pkmxj9gq/

In this solution you will use `float` in CSS to do the job *(like **Kate** does)*. A important thing to note is the first line of CSS, i put **`box-sizing: border-box;`**, with this you dont will have much trouble with borders and paddings, so dont wanna need to use **`calc(50% - 1xp)`** like **Kate** does *(but still can have to do some adjustments if you want to use margins)*.

Also, the class for a row on the grid system need the `:after` config, to clear the floating behavior below the floating line, and let the outter node grow the height to cover all the childs nodes *(the floating nodes)* inside it.

Most of the **CSS Grid Systems** out there use floats, some of them are using now `flexbox` these days.
One of the reasons to use these things is to create responsive layouts, with `media querys` you change the `columns` size to fit `100%` of the width and let they be one above the other. With flexbox you can config the columns of the box too.

Comment: You don't know how much I appreciate this! Very informative and super helpful! I can't thank you enough